# Unable to find NodeJSInstalls for Parsing TypeScript file using Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, typescript, nodes

i'm facing below issue while parsing TypeScript files in the Eclipse plugin project. Following are log details:

```
INFO [main] (GeneratorMain.java:178) - Start generate model STST0101_swap_js.xbl
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ts.eclipse.ide.internal.core.Trace.trace(Trace.java:89)
    at ts.eclipse.ide.internal.core.Trace.trace(Trace.java:61)
    at ts.eclipse.ide.internal.core.nodejs.NodejsInstallManager.loadNodejsInstalls(NodejsInstallManager.java:109)
    at ts.eclipse.ide.internal.core.nodejs.NodejsInstallManager.getNodejsInstalls(NodejsInstallManager.java:68)
    at com.sample.ts.nodejs.NodeJSProcess.getNodeJsPath(NodeJSProcess.java:125)
    at com.sample.ts.nodejs.NodeJSProcess.startServer(NodeJSProcess.java:198)
    at com.sample.ts.nodejs.NodeJSProcess.ensureRunning(NodeJSProcess.java:85)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParserClient.executeRequest(ScriptParserClient.java:43)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParserClient.parseString(ScriptParserClient.java:100)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParser.parse(ScriptParser.java:73)
    at com.sample.ts.ast.AST.parseString(AST.java:163)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.findClass(GeneratorBase.java:302)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.ensureClass(GeneratorBase.java:115)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.EventActionGenerator.doGenerate(EventActionGenerator.java:37)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.generate(GeneratorBase.java:58)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.generateXbl(GeneratorMain.java:198)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.generateFunctionUnit(GeneratorMain.java:168)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.execute(GeneratorMain.java:66)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.main(GeneratorMain.java:43)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParserClient.executeRequest(ScriptParserClient.java:52)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParserClient.parseString(ScriptParserClient.java:100)
    at com.sample.ts.tsparser.ScriptParser.parse(ScriptParser.java:73)
    at com.sample.ts.ast.AST.parseString(AST.java:163)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.findClass(GeneratorBase.java:302)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.ensureClass(GeneratorBase.java:115)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.EventActionGenerator.doGenerate(EventActionGenerator.java:37)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.generator.GeneratorBase.generate(GeneratorBase.java:58)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.generateXbl(GeneratorMain.java:198)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.generateFunctionUnit(GeneratorMain.java:168)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.execute(GeneratorMain.java:66)
    at com.sample.nmc.ts.GeneratorMain.main(GeneratorMain.java:43)
```

The plugin project runs perfectly fine if executed as Eclipse plugin. I face above error if i try executing it as Runnable JAR file.
Kindly provide necessary help

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to Eclipse Che?

Comment: @SergeyKabashnyuk i've removed the eclipse-che tag

Comment: @Angelo I have created an Eclipse plugin to parse TypeScript files using TypeScript IDE eclipse plugin. Now i need to create the independent JAR to execute in some other project. But above exception is being thrown when i execute it as runnable JAR file

Comment: To be honnest with you, it's hard to help you without seeing your code. You are using internal class of TypeScript IDE so you should never used but I'm open to change that according your need. Please share your code.